# Preciso que a variável recivedData que é declarada no inicio guarde o valor que lhe é atribuido na funçao e o mostre fora da função

Tags: javascript

```
   var recivedData;
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp;
    obj = { "table":"customers", "limit":100 };
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        recivedData=this.responseText;    
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange 
    document.getElementById("demais").innerHTML = recivedData;
```

xmlhttp.open("GET", "reg.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();                            console.log(recivedData);
var dataSource=recivedData;

Comment: Neste momento ela esta retornando undefined

Comment: Você está tentando acessar o valor antes que ele esteja disponível. Precisa entender como funcionam operações assíncronas.